# Basic Diagxy example fails

Tags: diagxy

Trying to use diagxy for the first time.  I'm trying to implement one of the simplest examples, the commutative square.  All the manuals I can find give the following for the most basic square:

```
$$\bfig\square[A‘B‘C‘D;f‘g‘h‘k]\efig$$
```

Even on an otherwise completely empty document this example fails

In the empty document, when I compile, I get:

```
"paragraph ended before \next was complete"
"Improper \prevdepth \end{document}"
```

plus about 10 more errors

I can get the number of errors down to 2 by changing it to

```
$\square[A‘B‘C‘D;f‘g‘h‘k]$
```

with this statement I get 2 errors.  The first is the same as the first above, the second is:

```
"missing $ inserted"
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: As always on this site: you're much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can just copy and test as is.

Answer (score 2):

The character that you see rendered as `’` in the documentation should be input as a back quote `` ` ``

```
\bfig\square[A`B`C`D;f`g`h`k]\efig
```

Use `tikz-cd`, instead of an old and unmaintained package.

Comment: use a better package sounds like exactly the right answer.  Thanks!

Comment: big thanks egreg!  tikz-cd is the package I should have been using for years now.  So much better!  omg! :)